# How to reduce letter spacing when text tries to wrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way with CSS to reduce the [letter spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp) when the text tries to wrap?

For example, if I have a paragraph within a fixed width parent like so:

```
| Here is some |
| text         |
```

Is it possible, instead of wrapping the text to the next line, to reduce the letter spacing automatically to force it to fit without overflowing the parent div, like so:

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rCekh/)

Comment: i think this is what you want http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_anim_letter-spacing

Comment: @rjdmello - I need to dynamically change the `letter-spacing` depending on whether the text is trying to wrap or not... Not animate my text.

Comment: @fizzix but that's very cool anyway haha

Comment: you may need to use jquery and do some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/rCekh/3/

Comment: @rjdmello - The text still wraps to the next line though..?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes - Agreed haha, looks pretty awesome.

Comment: final only for you :-) http://jsfiddle.net/rCekh/4/

Comment: @rjdmello - Once again, the text needs to stay on one single line.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rCekh/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and, as I expected, currently it isn't possible without javascript. If this isn't a problem for you check this answer: [CSS text justify with letter spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355009/css-text-justify-with-letter-spacing)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use white-space set according to you.

```
white-space:nowrap and letter-spacing:-1px;
```

Comment: As stated in my question, this has to be automated. Not by applying a class to each individual block of text that I need to reduce the letter spacing on.