# Is there a best way to justify h1 text to its containing div?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-justify

I would just like a div, in the center of the page, that contains one line (two words) of h1 text, and that text is justified to the length of the div; meaning, the letters space out (while maintaining their size) to occupy the entire width of the div, and do not go outside the div.  And, if I change the browser settings to shorten the width of the page (such as zoom in), the letters will condense (to a point, before breaking up to two lines).

I cannot realistically list all the things I have tried, to no avail.  Which includes all the suggestions I have seen on this site to date.

Is it really that complicated?  Or am I just missing something obvious?

Please, please help.

I apologize for the "subjective nature" of this request.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but this is the best I could come up with without using `@media` queries at specific breakpoints to separate the elements and have them break to 2 lines at a narrow width. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awpZvB

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355009/css-text-justify-with-letter-spacing

Comment: @MichaelCoker I suppose I could do that.  I guess I was just hoping for something that I wouldn't have to alter if I add another word.  But thanks.

Comment: @bloomers you bet. I would probably do this with javascript tho, and have javascript do all the work so the html would just be a tag with words.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the font size to change depending on window width?

In CSS, you can use the `vw` unit for `font-size`, so that would respond to the window width, but requires some trial-and-error, I guess.

Apart from that, there's a javascript plugin named `fittext` (http://fittextjs.com/) which does what you want. I used it on one website and it works quite reliably,